# How to add a reference line to the pyplot line chart ?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe for which I have drawn a line chart and added a reference number using the below code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.title('Parento Analysis',fontsize=20, color = 'blue')
plt.xlabel('Product', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Sales Quantity', fontsize=14)
plt.plot(parento['Cum_Product%'], parento['Cum_Sales%'],linewidth=3.0)
plt.plot([10, 10], [0, 80], 'k-', lw=1,dashes=[2, 2])
plt.plot([0, 10], [80, 80], 'k-', lw=1,dashes=[2, 2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

My solution seems a bit long for me.
Is there any other short way with which I can draw the reference line for (10,80)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure,

```
plt.plot([10, 10], [0, 80], 'k-', lw=1,dashes=[2, 2])
plt.plot([0, 10], [80, 80], 'k-', lw=1,dashes=[2, 2])
```

gives the same as

```
plt.plot([10, 10, 0], [0, 80, 80], 'k-', lw=1,dashes=[2, 2])
```

Plotting only a single line is also more efficient - although in the case of only 2 poins it wouldn't really matter.

If you need to draw these kinds of reference lines more often you could of course put it in a function,

```
import numpy as np
def refline(x, **kwargs):
    y = np.interp(x, parento['Cum_Product%'], parento['Cum_Sales%'])
    plt.plot([x, x, 0], [0, y, y], **kwargs)
```

and call it like

```
refline(10, color="k", lw=1, dashes=[2, 2])
```

Comment: Ernest , thanks for your answer
Is it possible to reference just one point on one axis and draw reference line on both axis. Just like what our code does. Thanks

Comment: You can write a function to do so. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question from the comments:

> Is it possible to reference just one point on one axis and draw reference line on both axis

You'd need your Parento line in a functional form, i.e. *Sales Quantity = f(Product)*. One way to solve for that *f* is to use interpolation:

```
from scipy import interpolate
f = interpolate.interp1d(parento['Cum_Product%'],  parento['Cum_Sales%'])
```

so now `f(10)` should return `80`. We can incorporate this into ImportanceOfBeingErnests function:

```
def refline(x, f, **kwargs):
    y = f(x)
    plt.plot([x, x, 0], [0, y, y], **kwargs)
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

X = np.array([1,2,4,6,12,20,28,40])
Y = np.log(X)

f = interpolate.interp1d(X,Y)
# You don't even have to pass f in depending on how general you need it to be
def refline(x, **kwargs):
        y = f(x)
        plt.plot([x, x, 0], [0, y, y], **kwargs)

plt.plot(X,Y,linewidth=3.0)
refline(10, color="k", lw=1, dashes=[2, 2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Even though `10` wasn't in my original `X`, because we're interpolating you can still draw a reference line to the correct point on your line.